# Unable to focus next input field in the same row

Tags: html, jquery

I have an HTML table and trying to focus the next input field in the same row. But when i press enter it focus to the next input but to the first row.

In the screenshot below my cursor is in qty column in the second row, when i press enter it focus to the red highlighted field, rather to focus green highlighted field.

[image]

I am using the following code. Appreciated if anyone could help me out.

```
$('#save-stage').on('keypress', function (event) {
        debugger
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.which : '');
        if (keycode == '13') {

            var columnIndex = $(event.target).closest('td').index();
            var headerName = $('#save-stage th').eq(columnIndex).text();
            if (headerName == "Qty") {
                $("#save-stage").find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").focus();
            }

            return false;

        }
    });
```

Comment: `th` equal *column* index?  Makes no sense.     Try `let idx = $(this).closest("td").index();  var th = $(this).closest("table").find("thead").find("th").eq(idx);`

Comment: `$('#save-stage th td').eq(columnIndex)` might also work

Comment: Unfortunately it does not worked. My code works well but focus to the first row. In my code how can we provide row index  $("#save-stage").find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").focus(); This will serve my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Any practical example will definitely help me, thanks.

Comment: @RaufAbid Why don't you provide example code so we can repoduce your probem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: By the way a legal attribute for input fields is `tabindex`. That controls cursors way when tab key has being pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution to my problem. I am focusing to the required **TD** to the specific row index getting dynamically. I would like to express my gratitude to all those who provided their inputs.

```
$('#save-stage').on('keypress', function (event) {

            debugger
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.which : '');
            if (keycode == '13') {

                var columnIndex = $(event.target).closest('td').index();
                var rowIndex = $(event.target).closest('tr').index();
                var headerName = $('#save-stage th').eq(columnIndex).text();
                if (headerName == "Qty") {

                    $("#save-stage > tbody > tr").eq(rowIndex).find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").focus();
                    $("#save-stage > tbody > tr").eq(rowIndex).find("td:eq(5) input[type='text']").select();
                }

                if (headerName == "Rate") {
                    $("#txtProductName").focus();
                }

                if (headerName == "Disc %") {
                    $("#txtProductName").focus();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, reference to the TR is missing and seems the #save-stage is referenced to the table (not TR) so you always end up to the first row using `eq()`. I modified the code by referencing to the current TR (using `$(this)`) also used **class** instead of **ID** to work with multiple rows:

```js
$('.save-stage').on('keypress', function (event) {
        debugger
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.which : '');
        if (keycode == '13') {

            var columnIndex = $(event.target).closest('td').index();
            var headerName = $("#th").find("td").eq(columnIndex).text();
            
            if (headerName == "Qty") {
                $(this).find("td").eq(4).find("input").focus();
            }

            return false;

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table border="1">
    <thead id="th">
        <td>NAME</td>
        <td>ITEMS</td>
        <td>RACK</td>
        <td id="test">Qty</td>
        <td>RATE</td>
        <td>DISC</td>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
    </thead>
    <tr class="save-stage">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input></td>
        <td><input></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
 
    </tr>
    <tr class="save-stage"">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input></td>
        <td><input></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code looks awsome. I give it a try and change my code as per your suggestion but no luck. I will try again tomorrow. Just a little question! Cannot we just give a row and column index to focus an input under html table, i also try like this but no succes: $("#save-stage").find("tr.eq(2) 
  td:eq(5) input[type='text']").focus()

Comment: You can hard code for a specific row and column but will not be general for all rows. in your comment `tr.eq(2)` should updated to `tr:eq(2)` or `find("tr").eq(2)`